# MultiRes modifer: subdivision level too low in viewport

Tags: modeling, modifiers, 3d-view, sculpt

I have set MultiRes subdivision level set to 4 for all three options (viewport, sculpt, and render). The modifier works as expected in sculpt mode and in renders, but when in the viewport (excluding sculpt mode) the modifier acts as if "Levels Viewport" is set to 2, rather than what it is actually set to (that being 4).

[image: Sculpt mode, MultiRes modifier works as expected with resolution of 4]

[image: Object mode (viewport), MultiRes modifier shows as if "Level Viewport" is set to 2]

Download the .blend file [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WNqZOXFpjJtqzTJXDekxKoCO2aD_2-lw/view?usp=sharing). Credit to Andy Goralczyk on Blender Studio.

(Blender 3.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify is turned on and set to 2 - this option sets the max subdivisions value for your scene. Either turn it off, or set Render Properties -> Simplify -> Max Subdivisions to 4 or higher.

[image]